# Find the greatest integer less than $\frac{1}{\sin^2(\sin(1))}$ without calculator.

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions, number-comparison

Find the greatest integer less than $$\frac{1}{\sin^2(\sin(1))}$$

This was on one of my tests. All angles in radians. Here's my work:
$$0<1<\frac{\pi}{3}<\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Since $\sin(x)$ is increasing in the first quadrant,
$$0<\sin(1)<\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}<\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=1<\frac{\pi}{2}$$
$\sin(1)$ radians and $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ radians also lie in the first quadrant, and $\sin^2(x)$ is increasing in the first quadrant
$$\sin^2(\sin(1))<\sin^2\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)<\frac{3}{4}$$
$$\frac{1}{\sin^2(\sin(1))}>\frac{4}{3}$$

But I cannot find an upper bound on my expression. Any help?

Comment: If $\sin(1)>\frac{\pi}{4}$ then $\frac{1}{\sin^2(\sin(1))}<2$

Comment: @Henry Yes, but is it possible to get $sin(1)>\frac{\pi}{4}$ without a calculator?

Comment: So we need to find something between $\sin(1)\approx 0.8414709848078965$ and $\frac{\pi}{4}\approx 0.7853981633974483$. Or maybe Taylor series of $\arcsin$?

Comment: @yukelid Yes, very easily: $$\sin 1 > 1 - \frac{1^3}{3!} = \frac{5}{6} > \frac{\pi}{4}\,.$$

Comment: @daniel nice. this is the easiest i have seen!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We'll prove that $$\frac{1}{\sin^2\sin1}<2,$$ for which it's enough to prove that $$\sin\sin1>\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$ or $$\sin1>\frac{\pi}{4},$$ for which it's enough to prove that $$\sin54^{\circ}>\frac{\pi}{4}$$ or
$$\frac{\sqrt5+1}{4}>\frac{\pi}{4}$$ or
$$\sqrt5+1>\pi.$$
Can you end it now?

I got the answer: $1$.

Comment: nice solution! 1 rad is very close to 57 degrees.

Answer (score 2):

$$1 >  \frac{7}{24}\pi \approx 0.916$$
$$\sin(1) > \sin\left(\frac{7}{24}\pi\right) = \frac12\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}} \approx 0.793 > \frac{\pi}{4} \approx 0.785$$
$$\frac{1}{\sin^2(\sin(1))} < \frac{1}{\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{4})}=2$$

so $$1 < \frac{1}{\sin^2(\sin(1))} < 2$$